# Error 91 Search and scrape web

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA, and trying to put together a code that will allow me to search a website for bond information, which is listed in my excel file, and pull back the bond's issue date.  I have been able to get to the website, and using <kbd>F8</kbd> to execute  the code manually, the code appears to work fine.  However, when I run the macro, I get

> Error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set.

I am unsure how to fix this issue, and I have tried to find earlier answers, as there is a lot of info on error 91.  But none seem to be able to help with my specific problem.

Please assist, thanks.

```
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 'special object variable representing the IE browser
Dim datelabel As String 
Dim x As String 'for the CUSIP number
Dim y As Integer 'integer variable we'll use as a counter
Dim result As String 'string variable that will hold our result link


'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
objIE.Visible = False

'navigate IE to this web page
objIE.navigate "https://emma.msrb.org/Search/Search.aspx"


'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop





'DATA SCRAPING Portion

  Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
  Set Doc = objIE.document

  'get issue date
  datelabel = Doc.getElementsByClassName("value")(0).innerText  'HERE IS WHERE I HAVE MY PROBLEM
  'MsgBox datelabel



End If
Loop



'close the browser
objIE.Quit
```

This is the html that I am trying to pull:

span class="value" 
from: 
https://emma.msrb.org/SecurityView/SecurityDetails.aspx?cusip=ACDB05F7DCC14B929AC9D2D082A3D9AE0

Comment: Are you really sure that with `F8` you get what you expect to be getting?
 Because `getElementsByClassName("value")` means that there is a class named `value` and this looks a bit wrong to me.

Comment: Hi Vityata, this was the from the web page's code:                            
 <span class="value">
                <span id="ctl00_mainContentArea_securityHeaderLabelsUserControl1_datedDateLabel" class="label">Dated Date:</span>
                <span id="ctl00_mainContentArea_securityHeaderLabelsUserControl1_datedDateDataLabel">11/25/2008</span></span>

Comment: I have checked and I do not see <span class="value"> in the page's code

Comment: Hi tomjohnriddle, did you search the web page that is listed?  Because this is not the page that the data is being pulled from.  The way the macro works, is that it takes you to the initial page (the one listed), enters in a bond number (from my excel file), hits the search "click", and pulls up the bond's specific page.  This is a new page, and it is here that I am trying to pull the data from.  This is also the page were I "right-clicked" over the bond's issue date, and hit "inspect", where the code has the class name "value".